# Branching not working in airflow as expected

Tags: airflow

In the below code, based on branch_decision(), it should pick either push_to_redshift_task or delete_from_redshift_task. But looks like both of these tasks are run always. How should I modify the airflow code to pick just one of these 2 tasks based on the outcome of branch_decision()?

```
@task(task_id="list_files_task")
def list_files():
    return oldest_files

@task(task_id="transform_files_task")
def transform_file(source_s3_key: str):
    return ids

@task.branch(task_id="branch_decision_task")
def branch_decision(source_s3_key: str):
    if "delete" in source_s3_key:
        return 'delete_from_redshift_task'
    else:
        return 'push_to_redshift_task'

@task(task_id="push_to_redshift_task")
def push_to_redshift(source_s3_key: str):
    ...

@task(task_id="delete_from_redshift_task")
def delete_from_redshift(syncari_ids_to_delete):
    ...


list_files_task = list_files()
transform_files_task = transform_file.expand(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
branch_decision_task = branch_decision.expand(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
push_to_redshift_task = push_to_redshift.expand(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
delete_from_redshift_task = delete_from_redshift.expand(syncari_ids_to_delete=transform_files_task.output)
cleanup_files_task = cleanup_files.expand(source_s3_key=list_files_task)

list_files_task >> transform_files_task >> create_table_task >> branch_decision_task >> [push_to_redshift_task, delete_from_redshift_task] >> cleanup_files_task
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. This looks like a bug, but you can achieve the desired functionality by converting `list_files` into a [TaskGroup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#taskgroups)

Here's a rough working example using your code as the foundation:

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group


files = ["delete_a", "b", "c"]


@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 2,  # If a task fails, it will retry 2 times.
    },
    tags=["example"],
)  # If set, this tag is shown in the DAG view of the Airflow UI
def map_branched_task_group():
    @task_group(group_id="files_group")
    def files_group(oldest_file):
        @task
        def create_table_task():
            ...

        @task(task_id="transform_files_task")
        def transform_file(source_s3_key: str):
            return source_s3_key

        @task.branch(task_id="branch_decision_task")
        def branch_decision(source_s3_key: str):
            if "delete" in source_s3_key:
                print("1")
                return "files_group.delete_from_redshift_task"
            else:
                print("0")
                return "files_group.push_to_redshift_task"

        @task(task_id="push_to_redshift_task")
        def push_to_redshift(source_s3_key: str):
            print("pushing to redshift")
            return ["id2"]

        @task(task_id="delete_from_redshift_task")
        def delete_from_redshift(syncari_ids_to_delete):
            print("deleting from redshift")
            return ["id1"]

        @task
        def cleanup_files(source_s3_key):
            ...

        list_files_task = oldest_file
        transform_files_task = transform_file(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
        branch_decision_task = branch_decision(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
        push_to_redshift_task = push_to_redshift(source_s3_key=list_files_task)
        delete_from_redshift_task = delete_from_redshift(
            syncari_ids_to_delete=transform_files_task
        )
        cleanup_files_task = cleanup_files(source_s3_key=list_files_task)

        (
            transform_files_task
            >> create_table_task()
            >> branch_decision_task
            >> [push_to_redshift_task, delete_from_redshift_task]
            >> cleanup_files_task
        )

    files_group.expand(oldest_file=files)


map_branched_task_group()
```